# RSA encrypt and decrypt in python for url

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, rsa

My task is to encrypt ID and pass to url. After then from url, fetch encrypted ID and decrypt the ID. I have to perform this task in python.
I am using RSA algorithm. 
I am able to do encryption of ID but I am stuck at decryption. Also I don't know how to decrease the length of the encrypted ID. Because when I add encrypted ID to url which is quite long.

Your help or any new suggestion will be helpful.
Thank you

Below is the code I am doing encryption

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import codecs

# Below commented code to Generate Private and Public Key
# key = RSA.generate(1024)
# private_key=key.exportKey()
# public_key=key.publickey().exportKey()

private_key = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIICXAIBAAKBgQCXmxgIXMkim2EBdiHjJLsgHxqhGUbO3n64MgAO+Ugbr2GVkchV
    aQUUWnNacmMOjq7h6OO1HLvH/tyow9d5XQlSjVlo28i9hHw40CTcBh0F3Fnzylwo
    8YHt1b4wSdO970ZnxSrtF6D8J3KPiPhzcJjrBpOU6seF46iuOwPFnjSg/QIDAQAB
    AoGAAUtvcBrYE4s/en4MxLN6mZ1KYpfO//3sbRxC3d3echtppO0CyJ/wotTcPqh9
    ahFpMuqvOcu4sCOKtNzp89JfPamHhjGU9xEGtqGWDWUrRjBAX22qq9Tkwlxhyoi1
    VYPK14nJPJYIFVA1tQvKNjQcEpN8rkaqesM9MGsbnL5r9C0CQQC4vmWhD7aHH3I7
    T9LTwvABXiaUYe39EOtJ8nc+4E9StwtUSQ/AGuGxrIyYfTHX70nWMDTikorEltWm
    rncHN1RvAkEA0hSow9/qe0CSmp5On14w6Ev+5glm6c2YqoaKAWfRggTrBQkIN1nh
    m0Wqbk4gqvxCtJ26Sgi4d62GG93WRipPUwJAe90L/qSuWII48JNgYyJ8EC6z5yCR
    k+7YEkhCsyFpjae0LNqfeMmNMLbjvQmTdZe2Balki9R8vbnznUG0BF6QeQJAdNxZ
    JNyiKv24j5oQUkarHg1oNb51KQndKr68dhuyR4lE0wA7Oc8d2KngLIv5UCQTVzWG
    Mzi2pJw6RbYZQ961UQJBAIbJOhfvy+T99aDxQKMWV0vEP93ebzlK1WW9MjhbzlIi
    UXfH1dJFtNZiZO5eM7oGl9Icyb6aGHx91c17zOptXHo=
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

public_key = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCXmxgIXMkim2EBdiHjJLsgHxqh
    GUbO3n64MgAO+Ugbr2GVkchVaQUUWnNacmMOjq7h6OO1HLvH/tyow9d5XQlSjVlo
    28i9hHw40CTcBh0F3Fnzylwo8YHt1b4wSdO970ZnxSrtF6D8J3KPiPhzcJjrBpOU
    6seF46iuOwPFnjSg/QIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

id = "5070930456"
h = SHA256.new(id)

priv_key = RSA.importKey(private_key)
pub_key = RSA.importKey(public_key)

singer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(priv_key)
signature = singer.sign(h)

hexify = codecs.getencoder('hex')
m = hexify(signature)[0]

#Output Encrypted ID
print m
```

Encrypted ID Output: 313729e2535c19f6a7121a8c80529b3d49ba1cdf7277aabddd2c04ff41ee85d55f5edc1c9e798da381cc0a5aabff529be62fa7ee6be61b1a0d25c57c45c9e6f65f726bb35fd5646bf7ce495d9a12bbe88688bd287bc667b5ff0f4a90218377cc2a0454e448ab53940a2457e20553deeb7b23c78d259660e9362be572384be344

Comment: Why do you want to send the encrypted id as a part of the URL?

Comment: for safety purpose @Sandeep

Comment: why should it be a part of the URL you can send a post request or send it as apart of headers

Comment: It is required by client @Sandeep